# How to remove a random element from an array. Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, logic, conditional-statements

So I'll start by explaining the context of the problem.

I have an array populated with multiple strings, and I want to select random elements from that array, but once an element is selected once, it cant be selected again. My solution for this was to simply delete it from the array.

I tried:

```
dogs_array =['Bob', 'Fred', 'Jeff', 'Rick', 'Alice', 'Joe','Max', 'Will']
for x in range(3):
    i  = random.randint(0, 7)
    print(dogs_array[i])
    dogs_array.remove(i)
```

However I receive the error: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

What should I do?

Comment: That's a list not an array

Comment: `del dogs_array[i]`

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to use `numpy` for this, the function [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) allows you to choose the size of your sample, rather than looping through `range(3)` as you were trying, and the argument `replace=False` guarantees that you don't select the same one twice:

```
import numpy as np

dogs_array =['Bob', 'Fred', 'Jeff', 'Rick', 'Alice', 'Joe','Max', 'Will']

my_selection = np.random.choice(dogs_array, size=3, replace=False)

>>> my_selection
array(['Fred', 'Alice', 'Jeff'], dtype='<U5')
```

Answer (score 2):

For those that search for an answer to the question (np.array, not list :) ) this might help

```
import random 
import numpy as np

dogs_array =np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
i  = random.randint(0, len(dogs_array ))
my_set = dogs_array [i]
dogs_array = np.delete(dogs_array, np.arange(i,i+len(my_set),1)).reshape([-1,len(my_set)])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `pop` method, very good for what you are doing here:

```
import random

dogs = ['Bob', 'Fred', 'Jess', 'Rick', 'Alice', 'Joe', 'Max', 'Will']

for x in range(3):
    selection = random.randint(0, len(dogs)-1)
    goner = dogs.pop(selection)
    print(goner)
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 pop.py
> Max
> Bob
> Joe
> ```

When using pop you would need to use `len` due to the fact the list is going to change sizes and you are going to need a random int for that new list size.

Answer (score 0):

The remove method in Python takes the element, not just an index.
Your solution will work if you use `dogs_array.remove(dogs_array[i])`

Comment: Sounds like overkill, no?

Comment: Hmm, that just prints 'None' 3 times. (?)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is trying to remove the index of the array which is not possible using **list.remove()**

It can be done by using the **del** method. Like ***del dogs_array[i]***